# PHP - Get number of different records (dates) in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way of getting the number of different records from a table in a database?

For Example: I have a table, which contains many records for one date and some other records for other dates. I need to count the number of different dates in the table, so classic mysql_num_rows isn't usable here.

Comment: use DISTINCT to the date column and use mysql_num_rows.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `GROUP BY`.
E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `date_field` FROM `some_table` GROUP BY `date_field`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(dates) FROM `table` GROUP BY dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT `recored_date` FROM `table`
```

or this to count the rows

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `record_date`) FROM `table`
```